# Can you Wish for a Glyph of Warding with an 8th Level Spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

If you have access to **Wish**, you can use *this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly Components. The spell simply takes effect.*

And **Glyph of Warding** specifies that you *can store a prepared spell of 3rd Level*(8th level for up cast) *or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph.*

Does **Wish** simply allow you to duplicate the full effect of both the spell of **Glyph of Warding** as well as the spell you would have prepared, or as per using **Wish** to create a glyph, would you be left with a **Glyph of Warding** that has no spell stored in it?

I have yet to find any mention of the interaction between these two spells other than storing **Wish** into a glyph, no where have I seen mentioned the question of if you can **Wish** for a **Glyph of Warding** pre-loaded with something like **Simulacrum**.

Alternatively, would it work, but just end up requiring you to spend the 12 hours casting time to load Simulacrum in the Glyph and still require you to have it under your prepared spell list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110949/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-sean).